# sort data values not by column

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a data frame consists of single column which needs to be sorted on data values and not by column

```
col = c("zyx","cad","nm,po,qr","ba,dc,uu")

df = data.frame(col)
```

need to get output column as follows

```
col_out =c("xyz","acd","mn,op,qr","ab,cd,uu")
df = data.frame(col,col_out)
```

I have tried with "Order" statement but unable to get desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option first splitting string on comma, then splitting them on every character and finally combining them in one string again.

```
sapply(strsplit(df$col, ','), function(x) 
  toString(sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(y) 
    paste0(sort(y), collapse = ''))))

#[1] "xyz"        "acd"        "mn, op, qr" "ab, cd, uu"
```